# Why nlohmann/json serialize "null" instead of "0" on double?

Tags: c++, json, serialization, null, nlohmann-json

Let say I partially init a native double array in `C++` and serialize it with `nlohmann/json`:

```
const int numPoints = 10;
double mLengths[numPoints];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    mLengths[i] = i + 0.1 * i; 
}

nlohmann::json jsonData;
jsonData["lengths"] = mLengths;
std::string serialized_string = jsonData.dump();
```

It will correctly serialize somethings like this:

```
{  
   "lengths":[  
      0.0,
      1.1,
      2.2,
      3.3,
      4.4,
      -9.255963134931783e+61,
      -9.255963134931783e+61,
      -9.255963134931783e+61,
      -9.255963134931783e+61,
      -9.255963134931783e+61
   ]
}
```

But sometimes, instead of take "random double" from memory, it store on the json the value null, so it will result somethings like this:

```
{  
   "lengths":[  
      0.0,
      1.1,
      2.2,
      3.3,
      4.4,
      -9.255963134931783e+61,
      -9.255963134931783e+61,
      null,
      -9.255963134931783e+61,
      -9.255963134931783e+61
   ]
}
```

And when I deserialize it back, it thrown me an exception `type must be number, but is null`.

Why does it serialize `null` instead of `0`? Does it takes from memory somethings "null"? Isn't 0 in C++?

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour of the serialisation step, and therefore paradoxically the entire program, is *undefined*.

In C++ you must *never* attempt to read uninitialised memory, *unless* you cast to an `unsigned char` type.

The "sometimes" nature of the varying output is a manifestation of that undefined behaviour.

Comment: Can you show to me an example how can a double stored as "null" instead of "0"?

Comment: @markzzz: That would be tough to cut without seeing all the serialisation code.

Comment: @markzzz: Not really, all the code in `dump` would need to be inspected.

Comment: Its a free library, its open: https://github.com/nlohmann/json/blob/develop/single_include/nlohmann/json.hpp#L13292